# pg-promise: Updating row with array text column with pgp.helpers.update

Tags: node.js, pg-promise

I am trying to update a text array column :

```
var data = [];

for (const tag of tags) {
    var tmp = {'rids': [rid], 'id': tag.id, 'uid' : uid};
    data.push(tmp);
}

const condition = pgp.as.format(' WHERE CAST(v.uid AS INTEGER) = t.uid and v.id = t.id');
const insertQuery = pgp.helpers.update(data, ['?id', '?uid', 'rids'], 'table_tags') + condition + ' ' + 'RETURNING t.tag';


return db.any(insertQuery);
```

This works but it replaces the columns value.

How to keep the current column value and append the new ones ?

Like this : `{somevalue, someothervalue, newinsertedvalue}`
Instead of : `{newinsertedvalue}`

This is the query i used to use in a php drupal project :

```
db_query("UPDATE table_tags set rids = rids || (:rid) WHERE uid = :uid and id = :id", array(':rid' => '{'.$rid.'}', ':uid' => $uid, ':id' => $tag_id));
```

Comment: You should include a PostgreSQL query example that works correctly for you, then you can be advised of the change in using `pg-promise`. Without it, it is not even related to `pg-promise`, rather to the query you want and its result expectation.

Comment: Thank you. This the working query example i want to generate :

`update "table_tags" as t set "rids"= t.rids || v."rids" from (values(154,1,1315709),(153, 1,1315709)) as v("id","uid", "rids") WHERE CAST(v.uid AS INTEGER) = t.uid and v.id = t.id RETURNING t.tag`

Not sure if pgp.helpers can handle the concat

Comment: That is quite different from what the `update` helper generates. It sets values, it does not concatenate them with such extra logic. You would have to provide a custom update generator.

Comment: For your special case, you can write the query statically, merging it with the dynamic part  - values, which you can generate via [helpers.values](https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.html#.values).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your value-concatenation logic is a special case, not supported by the default `update`. You will have to write the query statically, with the dynamic part - values, generated via [helpers.values](https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.html#.values) function.

```js
const values = helpers.values(data, ['id', 'uid', 'rids']);

const query = `UPDATE table_tags AS t SET rids = t.rids || v.rids FROM 
    (VALUES${values}) as v(id, uid, rids)
    WHERE CAST(v.uid AS INTEGER) = t.uid AND v.id = t.id RETURNING t.tag`.
```

Comment: Thank you ! Its much more elegant of what i did